# OpendKim dont find SigningTable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix-mta, opendkim

Today I installed and configured the opendkim program on my Linux server.

after I configured it and restarted it, I always get error 78 when restarting:

`opendkim: /etc/opendkim.conf: refile:        /etc/opendkim/SigningTable: dkimf_db_open(): No such file or directory`

opendkim.conf:

```
ExternalIgnoreList refile:      /etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts refile:   /etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
KeyTable refile:        /etc/opendkim/KeyTable
SigningTable refile:    /etc/opendkim/SigningTable
SignatureAlgorithm      rsa-sha256
```

ls -l opendkim:

```
-rw-rw---- 1 760 opendkim   81 Dez 25 12:04 KeyTable
-rw-rw---- 1 760 opendkim 1704 Dez 25 11:44 mail.private
-rw-rw---- 1 760 opendkim  506 Dez 25 11:44 mail.txt
-rw-rw---- 1 760 opendkim   52 Dez 25 12:06 SigningTable
-rw-rw---- 1 760 opendkim   17 Dez 25 11:53 TrustedHosts
```

Why opendkim doesnt find "SigningTable" ? I have no clue...

change the owner form the Directory
change the path
change the permission of Read and Write
restart the server

Comment: I solved it
in the opendkim.conf file there souldnt be whitespaces between the Options